# Deploying cordova to Xcode in vmware

Tags: xcode, cordova, visual-studio-2015, vmware

I have just started using cordova and ionic with vs2015. I am running this on a windows 10 machine. I have built the android side and put to store.

I have a version of mac running via vmware on the windows machine.  I have tried copying the xcode project file across manually and building, butrun into bui;d errors.  Is there a way of linking vs2015 ios build directly to the xcode on the vmmachine.

If not may some guidance on building and copying the correct parts for xcode.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to [run your app on the iOS Simulator](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ios/)

Make sure that you have installed the remote agent on a Mac that meets all system requirements, and that you have started the remote agent.

Make sure that you have specified iOS processing, the host name or IP address, port, and security PIN in Visual Studio.

1. With your app open in Visual Studio, choose iOS from the Solution
   Platforms list. If you don’t see this list, choose Solution
   Platforms from the Add/Remove Buttons list to display it.
2. In the simulator list, choose Simulator – iPhone or another iOS
   simulator.
3. Selecting the iOS Simulator Press F5 to start the app.

If the remote agent is set up correctly, Visual Studio deploys the app to the iOS Simulator on your Mac.

**iOS Simulator running on a Mac**

Tip If you are running a version of the iOS Simulator with a Retina display on a lower-resolution Mac with a non-Retina display, you may need to scale the emulator to 50% so the app will fit on the screen (choose Window, Scale).

If you have configured the remote build agent on your Mac as described in the article Install tools for iOS, you can build and run your app on an iOS device that is connected to your Mac or PC.